# CALayer with UIImageView

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have below code:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *img_Logo;
```

...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CALayer *ca_Logo = img_Logo.layer;
    ca_Logo.position = CGPointMake(400, 400);
    ca_Logo.duration = 2.0f;

    [ca_Logo setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

When a touch event is triggered, the logo will disappear, but when I remove `ca_Logo.duration = 2.0f`, that `ca_Logo` will move, but it was not an animation, just instantly disappear and appear to a new location.

Is there anything wrong with it? `img_Logo` is an `UIImageView` with `IBOutlet` or I need to program it without Interface builder?

I want to move the image from `CGPointMake(400, 400)` to `CGPointMake(200, 400)`

Comment: what effect do you want to achieve

Comment: I want to move the image from CGPointMake(400, 400) to CGPointMake(200, 400)

Comment: just change your UIImgeView's frame. don's need to dig into layer, don't need to redraw the layer

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to program it without using the interface builder try this code

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_Logo.png"];
CALayer *img = [CALayer layer];
img.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
img.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200);
img.position = CGPointMake(400, 400);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:img];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to animate from one frame to another, try below:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.img_Logo setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 400, youImageViewWidth, youImageViewHeight)];
    }];
```

I don't get your point using touchesBegan and touchesMoved